# NSSplitView Collapse Event

Tags: cocoa, nssplitview

I'm trying to implement an NSSplitView similar to Xcode where you can collapse a view by dragging its handle to under half its width and it will collapse automatically.  I have that part working, but I need to update the state of a button in the toolbar when this happens.  I tried listening to splitViewDidResizeSubviews and checking if the splitView's view is collapsed, but that method fires 16 times with collapsed == true, so I don't think I want to update the button's state 16 times.  Is there a cleaner way to do this?  I'm new to Cocoa, but from what I've seen, I would expect there to be some way to just say bind this button's state to the isCollapsed property and be done with it.  Does such a thing exist?

Comment: A split view can have many collapsable subviews so NSSplitView doesn't have one `isCollapsed` property.

Answer (score 1):

If you subclass your `NSSplitViewController` you can add a listener for the SplitViewItem's `isCollapsed` property:

```
class MySplitViewController: NSSplitViewController {

    var observer: NSKeyValueObservation?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do view setup here.

        let sideViewSplitViewItem = splitViewItems[0]

        observer = sideViewSplitViewItem.observe(\.isCollapsed, options: [.initial, .new]) {splitViewItem, _ in
            print("Sidebar collapsed state changed to: \(splitViewItem.isCollapsed)")
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to see what bindings are available is to check the docs, specifically the [Cocoa Bindings Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CocoaBindingsRef/CocoaBindingsRef.html) (look in the sidebar for the *view* you're after).

[image]

`NSSplitView` doesn't have the binding you describe, so I think you're on the right track with your current approach. Of course, you don't need to *update* the button's state sixteen times, just *check* it's value each time, and update it if needs be. It might seem a bit wasteful, but checking the value of a bool is a very cheap operation, and you won't notice any kind of performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

While `NSSplitView` has no event or observable property for when one of it's subviews is "collapsed", the immediate subview itself will have its `hidden` property set to `YES`.

So you can either observe the subview's `hidden` property yourself, or if you're creating your own custom subview of `NSView`, you can override the `-(void) setHidden:(BOOL)hidden` to catch the event.

I do the latter, and it works correctly every time.

```
-(void)setHidden:(BOOL)hidden
{
    [super setHidden:hidden];

    // Insert code to react to the "collapsed" event here.
    // (You're likely going to tell your parent view,
    // self.window.windowController, or something.)
}
```

Of course the `setHidden` method / `hidden` property can **in theory** be called for purposes other than from `NSSplitView` "collapsing" your view, but this is very unlikely to ever happen in practice.